# when i upload my website another one is automatically updated

Tags: security, web

One of my websites [http://hitechcentralair.com](http://hitechcentralair.com/) is automatically copied to another domain name http://hitechcentralair.net/. I don't know who is the owner of .net website.

### ---

When i update my hitechcentralair.com website hitechcentralair.net is being update automatically

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your hosting company and ask them about the issue.

Maybe your hosting company included the .net domain when you purchased the .com domain.

Its possible that the .net domain has the same ip address as the .com domain and both are referring to the same website

Comment: I already contacted my hosting company. They says that this is issue is not related to our hosting services.

Comment: You should do a WHOIS lookup on the hitechcentralair.net domain. It will give you contact information about the owners of the domain. Contact the owners and resolve your issue. You can use this link to make the WHOIS request: https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=hitechcentralair.net